# Read a number in a textfile and when get 150 reset to one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with the "1.hello" text, I want to read the number and every time I execute this script the number increase by 1. But when reach "150.hello", reset the text to "1.hello". Something like this:

> 1.hello
>
> 2.hello
>
> 3.hello
>
> 4.hello
>
> ...
>
> 150.hello
>
> 1.hello

```
from datetime import datetime

ruta = "xxx\\1.txt"

with open(ruta, "a+") as fichero_fecha:
    fecha_actual = datetime.now()
    if fichero_fecha.tell():
        fichero_fecha.seek(0)
        fecha = datetime.strptime(next(fichero_fecha).rstrip(), "%Y/%m/%d")
        cont = int(next(fichero_fecha).split(".")[0])  
        if (fecha_actual - fecha).days > 2:
            fichero_fecha.seek(0)
            fichero_fecha.truncate()
            fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\n')
            fichero_fecha.write(f'{cont + 1}.hello\n')
    else:
        fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\n1.txt\n')

with open("xxx\\Innplay\\1.txt", 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()


filedata = filedata.replace('150', '1')


with open("xxx\\1.txt", 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

This works but seems a bit bad.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far. Attach your code

Comment: Consider using the modulo operator `%`

Comment: Hint: 1/ read the file 2/ decode the number 3/ increase the number and if it is greater that 150 set it to 1 4/ write the file back.

Comment: The text file has already all the rows in it? Or your script adds a row each time it is run?

Comment: Is the second line of the file (first line is a date), just remplace "1.hello" by "2.hello" when executed, until 150, then reset to "1.hello".